# How to prove $\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{12}x^2+o(x^2),(x\to0)$ using Taylor's Formula?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{12}x^2+o(x^2),(x\to0)$$

I have attempted to expand the multinomial $e^x-1$ by using Taylor's Formula, and I got this:
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\frac{x}{x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^2)}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2!}+o(x)},$$
which seems to have nothing to do with the multinomial I want.

I suppose the multinomial $e^x-1$ must be transferred to another form before Taylor's Formula is applied.

Comment: "I have attempted to expand the multinomial $e^x−1$ using Taylor's Formula, only to find that the result I get is totally different from the result given" Please show what you got, otherwise we are just whistling in the wind.

Comment: have you ever heard of the geometric series?

Comment: Please correct the step from $x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^2)$ (since, presumably, $0$ should read $o$) to $1+\frac{x}{2!}+o(x^3)$, which is wrong.

Comment: @Did Please tell me why. I think $o(x^3)$ should be smaller than $o(x^2)$.

Comment: Because $x+\frac{x^2}2+o(x^2)=x\left(1+\frac{x}2+o(\text{___})\right)$.

Comment: @Did I cannot see your formula clearly, it includes something like "o(___)".

Comment: Yeah, and you are supposed to fill the $\text{___}$ inside the $o(\text{___})$.

Comment: OK, thank you for motivating me to think independently:)

Comment: And I'm understand now!

Comment: "which seems to have nothing to do with the multinomial I want" Well, actually, from where you got, note that $$\frac1{1+u}=1-u+o(u)$$ hence your last expansion yields $$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\frac1{1+\tfrac{x}2+o(x)}=1-\frac{x}2+o(x).$$ To go further, one should use $$\frac1{1+u}=1-u+u^2+o(u^2)$$ and compute $a$ such that $$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\frac1{1+\tfrac{x}2+ax^2+o(x^2)}$$ to deduce that $$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1-\left(\frac{x}2+ax^2+o(x^2)\right)+\left(\frac{x}2+ax^2+o(x^2)\right)^2+o(x^2)=\ldots$$ Can you finish this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30716/discussion-between-sun-qingyao-and-did).

Comment: @Did Yes, I can. Thank you so much!

Comment: Then you might want to post your solution as an answer below and even, after a while, accept it.

Comment: @Did But it's in fact your answer, is it moral?

Comment: Yes, even recommended by the site. Go ahead!

Comment: @Did Got that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$A=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$$
Applying Taylor's formula to $e^x-1$, we get:
$$A=\frac{x}{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)-1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)}$$
Let $u=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)$, then $u\to0$. Since $\frac{1}{1+u}=1-u+u^2+o(u^2)$ when $u\to0$, the multinomial above can be written as:
$$1-[\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)]+[\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)]^2+o\{[\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)]^2\}$$
Expand it violently. The last term
$o\{[\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2)]^2\}$ is $o(x^2)$ because $\frac{x^2}{4}$ is the lowest term in that multinomial. Then note that $x^3$, $o(x^3)$, $x^4$ and $o(x^4)$ are all $o(x^2)$, so we can merge every such term into $o(x^2)$. Doing so, one gets finally:
$$A=1-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{12}x^2+o(x^2)\qquad(x\to0)$$

Comment: @Did Thanks for your instruction.

Comment: Nice solution. +1.

Comment: I like the idea of a "violent" expansion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a lengthy calculation by definition and using L'Hospital's rule tons of times - the approach by multiplication of two power series is what you should use.

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{e^x-1}\stackrel{L'H}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{e^x}=1
$$

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left.\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right|_{x=0}=\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{e^x x-e^x+1}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}\stackrel{L'H}{=}\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{x}{2 \left(e^x-1\right)}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x \left(e^x x+x-2 e^x+2\right)}{\left(e^x-1\right)^3}\stackrel{L'H}{=}
$$
$$
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+e^x (2 x-3)+3}{3 \left(e^x-1\right)^2}\stackrel{L'H}{=}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4 e^x (x-1)+x+4}{-12 e^x+9 e^{2 x}+3}\stackrel{L'H}{=}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4 e^x (x-1)+4 e^x+1}{18 e^{2 x}-12 e^x}=\frac{1}{6}
$$
THus:
$$
\frac{x}{e^{x}-1}=1-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2!\cdot 6}x^2+o(x^2)
$$